# Why do I still have a menu button?

Tags: android, menu

I'm using the `Holo.Light.Dialog` theme for one of my activities.  For some reason, when run on an ICS phone with on-screen keys, it gives me a soft menu key.  This key does nothing, I have no menu, and I can't seem to get rid of it.  The strange thing is, on an ICS tablet (same settings, just a larger screen) I don't get the software menu key.

I tried using `Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar(.MinWidth)`, thinking that the reason I was getting a menu key was a dialog has no title bar, and the app assumed I still wanted a menu key. I'd hoped telling it I didn't want an action bar would fix it, but that didn't seem to help.

Any ideas on how to force it to go away?

Activity XML:

```
<activity android:label="@string/login" 
        android:name=".login" 
        android:excludeFromRecents="false" 
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"/>`
```

Edit: For additional clarification, my MinSDK is 11, and targetSDK is 14.  Both should allow it to not use the menu button.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="14" /> element appears before the <application> element in your manifest.

Comment: Yep, it is.

   `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" 
              android:targetSdkVersion ="14"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to have the action bar in your holo theme.  In your example you have Theme.Holo.Light.**Dialog** and you said you did it a different theme without the Action Bar.  Try just plain Theme.Holo.Light.

From the android dev blog, ["Say goodbye to the menu button"](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html)

> If you set either minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion to 11 or higher,
>   the system will not add the legacy overflow button. Otherwise, the
>   system will add the legacy overflow button when running on Android
>      3.0 or higher. **The only exception is that if you set minSdkVersion to 10 or lower, set targetSdkVersion to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not 
>   use ActionBar, the system will add the legacy overflow button when
>
>   running your app on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher.**

which is what you are describing as happening.

Comment: I read that, but it states that this only happens with a minSDKVersion to 10 or lower, which is not what I have. I have it set to 11.  There has to be a way to use a dialog without a menu key.  If I set it to the Theme.Holo.Light, it works fine, but the activity is not one that works as a full screen really.  I suppose I could make it a dialog only on a tablet, but I'd rather keep things consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Delete the menu item if it exists in R.menu file.